# How to change Folder structure template for Importing/Comparing a Database?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

Is there a way to customize the folder structure for objects which get created in the project when importing a Database, or doing a schema comparison?

Is there a customizable template file used by Visual Studio to perform the action of including generated object in the solution.

**Example:**

By default, a Table and all its Indexes get created in "Tables" Folder, in a single file.
I would like to split these into separate files. Same goes for Statistics.

Here is an image of Folder Structures:
 - Server Object Explorer
 - Solution Explorer (what i would like it to look like)

[image: side-by-side Object Explorer and Solution Explorer]

Note:

I know that when doing comparison I can prepare a folder in my solution, then drag the desired objects, but that is not an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, I don't think there is way to specify folder structures apart from these default import options (Schema, Object type, schema\object type).

Well, you can split them up manually and create them on separate folders but its lot of manual work based on how many objects you have. but the publish/Script generation/Compare are not affected by this move.

Comment: I was wondering if anyone was able to find any hidden / internal template files, or something similar, which predefined these folder structures and allowed customization.